# How do I Replace 2 name specific values with a respective value and set all the other values to 0

Tags: python, replace

So I am working on a soccer project and I am creating a Column stating how many point were gaining in a match, This data set specifically follows Tottenham and so I only want points to reflect their progress, So if the FTR, Final time Result Column Says Tottenham I want the point column to say 3, if it says Draw they get 1, and if it says any other team I want it to say 0. How would I do this?

This is what I have tried:

```
conditions = [Tottenham['Points'].eq('Tottenham'),
             Tottenham['Points'].eq('Draw')]


choices = ['3','1','0']

Tottenham['Points'] = np.select(conditions,choices,default=Tottenham['Points'])
```

This however set all values to 0 but if I take the 0 away from choices it leaves the team name Instead of a 0 for the losses

Any Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Remove `'0'` from `choices` and try `Tottenham['Points'] = np.select(conditions,choices,default='0')`

Comment: SURELY you want those to be integers and not strings.